# table <td> element content not read out by NVDA screen reader, however read out by VoiceOver

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

The first two td elements are being focused but the contents are not being read out by NVDA. However the contents are read out correctly by VoiceOver. I would like the contents of these first two elements to be read out by NVDA as well as VoiceOver.

```
<table class="nhsuk-table" tabindex="0">
          <caption class="nhsuk-table__caption">{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.heading' | locale }}</caption>
          <tr class="nhsuk-table__row">
            <th id="title_{{loop.index}}" class="nhsuk-table__header" scope="col"><strong>{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.table.title' | locale }}</strong></th>
            <th id="description_{{loop.index}}" class="nhsuk-table__header" scope="col"><strong>{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.table.description' | locale }}</strong></th>
            <th class="nhsuk-table__header" scope="col"><strong>{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.table.due' | locale }}</strong></th>
            <th class="nhsuk-table__header" scope="col"><strong>{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.table.done' | locale }}</strong></th>
          </tr>
          {% for task in stage.tasks %}
            <tr scope="row" class="nhsuk-table__row">
              <td class="nhsuk-table__cell" aria-labelledby="title_{{loop.index}}" tabindex="0">{{ ('workflow.manageKpis.tasks.' + task.taskCode + '.title') | locale }}</td>
              <td class="nhsuk-table__cell" aria-labelledby="description_{{loop.index}}" tabindex="0"><strong>{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.table.from' | locale }}</strong> {{ ('workflow.manageKpis.tasks.' + task.taskCode + '.from') | locale }} <br><strong>{{ 'workflow.manageKpis.table.to' | locale }}</strong> {{ ('workflow.manageKpis.tasks.' + task.taskCode + '.to') | locale }}</td>
              <td class="nhsuk-table__cell">
                <label class="nhsuk-label nhsuk-u-visually-hidden" id="error_{{ task.dueDaysFieldName }}" for="{{ task.dueDaysFieldId }}">{{ ('workflow.manageKpis.tasks.' + task.taskCode + '.title') | locale }} {{ 'workflow.manageKpis.validation.dueDays' | locale }}</label>
                <input class="nhsuk-input nhsuk-input--width-2 {{ 'nhsuk-textarea--error' if error.fieldErrors[task.dueDaysFieldName] }}" id="{{ task.dueDaysFieldId }}" name="{{ task.dueDaysFieldName }}" type="text" value="{{ values[task.dueDaysFieldName] }}" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2">
              </td>
              <td class="nhsuk-table__cell">
                <label class="nhsuk-label nhsuk-u-visually-hidden" id="error_{{ task.doneDaysFieldName }}" for="{{ task.doneDaysFieldId }}">{{ ('workflow.manageKpis.tasks.' + task.taskCode + '.title') | locale }} {{ 'workflow.manageKpis.validation.doneDays' | locale }}</label>
                <input class="nhsuk-input nhsuk-input--width-2 {{ 'nhsuk-textarea--error' if error.fieldErrors[task.doneDaysFieldName] }}" id="{{ task.doneDaysFieldId }}" name="{{ task.doneDaysFieldName }}" type="text" value="{{ values[task.doneDaysFieldName] }}" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2">
              </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

Comment: What is `loop.index` and does it increment with each row? If so could you just check that the first `<th>` with `id="title_{{loop.index}}"` is the same as the first `<td>` `aria-labelledby="title_{{loop.index}}"` within the loop in the outputted HTML. It could be that you have an ID mismatch on the `aria-labelledby` that VoiceOver is ignoring but NVDA is throwing an error on.

Comment: You should print only the final HTML, not he django template so it is easy to help you out.

Comment: Can you try? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for `forloop.counter`?